# SharePoint 2013 list items paging

Tags: development, 2013, sharepoint-online, spquery, paging

I'm trying to make a webpart with list items paging. I followed this link http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/03/step-by-step-guide-to-implement-paging.html
and on SharePoint 2010 server it works good, but on 2013 it doesn't.

```
public SPListItemCollection GetTestItems(string pagingInfo)

   {
        SPWeb objWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPListItemCollection collection;
        SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();

        objQuery.RowLimit = (uint)MaxItemsOnPage;

        objQuery.Query = Camlex.Query().OrderBy(i => i[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created] as Camlex.Desc).ToString();
        objQuery.ViewFields = Camlex.Query().ViewFields(i => i["Title"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pagingInfo))
        {
            SPListItemCollectionPosition position = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(pagingInfo);
            objQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
        }

        collection = objWeb.Lists["testList"].GetItems(objQuery);
        return collection;
    }
```

When pagingInfo string is not null, it means when I push "next" and
pagingInfo = "Paged=TRUE&p_ID=3&p_Created=20130502%2022%3A19%3A00", the query return collection with 0 items.

I tried to remove p_Created=20130502%2022%3A19%3A00 from paging info string and don't use ordering in query it works. But I need to sort it by Created field, descending.

I make p_Created value like

> SPEncode.UrlEncode( Convert.ToString(collection[collection.Count - 1]["Created"]));

Maybe datetime formating in incorrect for sharepoint 2013 or they changed something in pagingInfo string format?

Comment: why don't you use, allowpaging=true for gridview ?

Comment: actually, I need to make paging for asp repeater, but I train on this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem sorting items by ID instead of Created field. So I think problem is in datetime format, I didn't find how to fix it.